# Is there anyway to read the service recovery option for a windows service in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi

We are developing an application to monitor the services, disk and events of a windows server.

We have a requirement to read the service recovery option and store it into the database table.

So I need to read the service recovery option for a Windows service, through C#.

Please provide any suggestions for this.

Comment: This could get very political. I can suggest many things. So, I suggest you try somthing. If it does not work, post your code and maybe we can help you better.

Comment: @AlexMendez: Yes Alex , Please provide the suggestion on this. If does  not works, i will post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to some PInvoke. This may help,

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/738444-recovery-settings-windows-service

Comment: :No man it doesn't helps me. Since i have the same code. I have no clue to how to implement this in C#

Comment: There is a sample code at PInvoke website. ı always use this site for Windows API. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/queryserviceconfig2.html